# Unable to kill a docker which restart each 10 seconds

Tags: docker, openvpn, raspberry-pi4

I have problems with a heretic docker container... I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn), trying to build a OpenVPN in my new raspberry (the first one in my life)... and I think I did something really wrong... I tried to run it with reset policy: "always"

This container has an error each time I try to run it,

> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

It tries to run each 10 seconds during 3 seconds, more or less, and always with a different Docker Container ID. It runs with different PID, too...

I've tried some solutions I've found on the Internet, trying to stop this madness...

Comment: are you using systemd script?

Comment: Maybe I've tried to use it, but I can't remember... It could happen a month ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using systemd script.

You should try with this command.
`systemctl stop docker-openvpn@NAME.service`
replace `NAME` with whatever name you have given to your service.

It is stated in their documentation

```
In the event the service dies (crashes, or is killed) systemd will attempt to restart the service every 10 seconds until the service is stopped with **systemctl stop docker-openvpn@NAME.service**
```

Checkout following [link](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/blob/master/docs/systemd.md)

In case you forgot your service name, you can run this command and check your service name
`systemctl --type=service`